# Restricting access to AWS lambda flask application

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, whitelist

We deployed our flask application to AWS lambda and would like to restrict to access to it to:

- Our development team (some external IP for everyone)
- Wordpress server (static IP)
- Bitbucket (for automatic deploys to lambda)
- Google oAuth2 (callback function to lambda)

The first two are fairly easy to accomplish by whitelisting the respective IP in the AWS Gateway or in flask itself. However, the latter two are a bit more tricky since there's no static IP for the bitbucket pipeline nor when receiving the oauth2 callback from Google.

I've looked at the referer in the Http header to identify Google's callback which works but it can be spoofed easily...

Is there a sophisticated way of locking the app down to the above sources?

Here is the version I've got so far

```
def whitelist_handler():
    whitelist_ips = os.getenv('WHITELIST_IPS')
    allow_access = True

    if whitelist_ips:
        whitelist_ips = whitelist_ips.split(',')
        referer = request.headers.get('Referer', '')

        whitelist_domains = ['https://accounts.google.com/signin/']

        if request.remote_addr not in whitelist_ips and not any([referer.startswith(domain) for domain in whitelist_domains]):
            allow_access = False

    if not allow_access:
        abort(401)
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need to whitelist bitbucket.  If bitbucket is currently CI/CDing automatically to the lambda, there is no need to whitelist it in your apps code is there?

Comment: I'm using `zappa` as the deployment tool; at the end, `zappa` will try to access the root `/` to check if it's reachable, so if the server hasn't been whitelisted, that will fail

Comment: @wasp256 Are you able to set the url `zappa` will try to access to something other than root `/`?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the documentation that that's possible; also to what would you set it?

Answer (score 3):

**Bitbucket**

For Bitbucket, the pipelines do actually have static IP addresses as listed [on the docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html).

**Google OAuth**

For OAuth, I'm not sure what you're doing here but no part of the OAuth flow involves the provider (Google) needing to send web requests to your application. OAuth works entirely off redirecting the user (who should already have access through your other rules). You can read about this flow [here](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#authorization).

So as long as your rules allow your **users** IPs then there's nothing you need to do for Google. This flow is why it's possible to use OAuth for local or intranet applications.

Comment: Was able to whitelist bitbucket through the link; however, for the Google oAuth2 yes you're right, the callback will contain the users own public IP so whitelisting that will not work. Is there a best practice to ensuring that the request is coming from the oauth2 process?

Comment: You might want to have a read of how oauth works. You should validate the response from the server using process described in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#webserver) where you exchange the code for a token.